# fill na according to certain conditionals of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have the following table:

| State | Municipality | Date of Project | Poverty (year) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aguascalientes | Aguascalientes | 2003 |  |
| Jalisco | Chapala | 2004 |  |
| Jalisco | Chapala | 2010 |  |
| Jalisco | Chapala | 2015 |  |

In it I have to fill the column `poverty` according to the columns before it.
The following table is the one which I am going to use in order to fill the information of the first table:

| State | Municipality | 2010 | 2015 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aguascalientes | Aguascalientes | 65.8 | 78.5 |
| Jalisco | Chapala | 45 .3 | 43.1 |
| Durango | Durango | 12.4 | 13.4 |
| Guanajuato | Leon | 15.2 | 13.2 |

What I need to do is with the information that have in `2010` and `2015` I have to fill the `poverty` column according to the year of `Date of Project`, `State` and `Municipality`. Additionally, if the year (of `Date of Project`) is between 2000:2012 I have to fill it with the `2010` column. On the other hand, if the year is between 2013:2020, the `2015` column should be the one I need to fill with.

Answer (score 2):

You can first left-merge two dataframes (to align them), and then use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```py
result = df1.merge(df2, on=['State', 'Municipality'], how='left')

condlist = [result['Date of Project'].between(2000,2012),
            result['Date of Project'].between(2013,2020)]
choicelist = [result['2010'], result['2015']]
result['Poverty (year)'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)

result.drop(columns=['2010', '2015'], inplace=True)
```

**Result:**

```py
            State    Municipality  Date of Project Poverty (year)
0  Aguascalientes  Aguascalientes             2003           65.8
1         Jalisco         Chapala             2004           45.3
2         Jalisco         Chapala             2010           45.3
3         Jalisco         Chapala             2015           43.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['Aguascalientes', 'Jalisco', 'Jalisco', 'Jalisco'],
                    'Municipality': ['Aguascalientes', 'Chapala', 'Chapala', 'Chapala'],
                    'Date of Project': ['2003', '2004', '2010', '2015'],
                    'Poverty': [None, None, None, None]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['Aguascalientes', 'Jalisco', 'Durango', 'Guanajuato'],
                    'Municipality': ['Aguascalientes', 'Chapala', 'Durango', 'Leon'],
                    '2010': [65.8, 45.3, 12.4, 15.2],
                    '2015': [78.5, 43.1, 13.4, 13.2]})

df1['Date of Project'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date of Project'])

df1['Poverty'] = df1.apply(lambda x: df2[(df2['State'] == x['State']) & (df2['Municipality'] == x['Municipality'])]['2010'].values[0] if x['Date of Project'].year <= 2012 else df2[(df2['State'] == x['State']) & (df2['Municipality'] == x['Municipality'])]['2015'].values[0], axis=1)

print(df1)
```

```
>>> print(df1)
            State    Municipality Date of Project  Poverty
0  Aguascalientes  Aguascalientes      2003-01-01     65.8
1         Jalisco         Chapala      2004-01-01     45.3
2         Jalisco         Chapala      2010-01-01     45.3
3         Jalisco         Chapala      2015-01-01     43.1
```

Comment: Thank you a lot
I was also thinking in something like this but yours exceeded my knowledge, thank you again